# Interpreting the meaning of a text without delimiters

Tags: text, combinatorics

I am given a text without delimiters and a dictionary. I have to find all the interpretations of the text, i.e. all the ways I can put spaces between characters so that I produce a meaningful text with respect to a dictionary.

For example:

```
"Agoodday"
```

could be:

```
"A good day"
```

or:

```
"Ago odd ay"
```

What is this problem called? Does it have a name in literature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broader mathematical problem falls under Pattern Recognition. 
When applied specifically to language texts, this is [Word Segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_segmentation).